# treemap highcharts group by

Tags: highcharts, group-by, treemap

I have designed a treemap using highcharts with custom algorithm.It has a drilldown to 1 level. There is a drop down for my chart and it has two options for selection. treemap is displayed on the basis of dropdown selection which has a group by feature implemented using underscore.js library. The feature is working fine. But the problem is, all the tiles which are grouped together, are placed next to each other. My requirement is : i want all those tiles to be packed in one big tile with one label. something like header title in D3(exactly the same). Please let me know how to go about it. Is it something like treemap within a treemap? Also i wanted to know if its feasible to have different labels and tooltips for parent and children in the same treemap. any leads would be helpful.

[actual image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzCcQ.png)

Comment: Live example, fiddle, or code?

Comment: Provide a picture for actual and wanted will be helpful

Comment: Do you mean something like this: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/treemap-with-levels ?

Comment: I have edited the question and added the image. That is what i am getting now. grouped tiles are placed next to each other. i am expecting something like this : http://www.billdwhite.com/wordpress/wp-content/js/treemap_headers_02.html. A common label for all the grouped tiles. Tiles should be equal though.

Comment: @SebastianBochan That is pretty much what i need but i want all the squares which are inside and outside to be equal sized.

Comment: You could set same values for each point to have something like this chart: http://jsfiddle.net/ygrrb50s/